# Why am I getting error in row.join() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to generate a csv file using the next code.

```
function generaBlue() {
  var taula = $("#divTaula")[0].childNodes;

  var id = taula[0].getAttribute("id");
  console.log(id.substr(0, id.indexOf("_")));
  let table = $("#" + id.substr(0, id.indexOf("_"))).DataTable();
  let data = table.rows().data();
  let text = "";
  data.map((row) => (text += row.join(";") + "\n"));
  let blob = new Blob([text], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" });
  saveAs(blob, "prova.csv");
}
```

And row.join(';') is returning this error:

> TypeError: row.join is not a function

Comment: What is `data`? For this code to work, it needs to be an array of arrays or an array of things that have a `.join()` method.

Comment: On a separate note, don't use `.map()` when you do simple iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a regular loop.

Comment: It depends on how you pass your data in datatable. Please have a look of this [discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/37952/how-i-get-all-data-in-the-table-help).

Comment: [Console return](https://ibb.co/Y2qZ4L8) if I show the variable data in the console, it shows an array but detects object type.  Even though I'm not totally sure about it.

Comment: Better to `console.log` the `row` variable... it's clearly looping over *something*

Comment: According to the docs [`rows().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) returns *"DataTables API instance with data for each row from the selector in the result set. Each entry is the original data source object for that row, be it an array, object or Javascript object instance"*. So `data` is an array, but the elements of that data may be arrays or objects. And if they are objects, there is no `join()`.

Comment: I understand your point view, then which would be the best way/method to join each row with a separator to generate the csv file

Comment: @AleixMartí, please try the code `data.forEach(row => { console.log(row); });` to show us the data structure.

Comment: If the current `row` really is an object, you can use `let text = data.reduce((a, c) => a  + Object.values(c).join(";") + "\n", "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was receiving an array of objects that do not accept the join function.

```
function generaBlue() {
  var taula = $("#divTaula")[0].childNodes;

  var id = taula[0].getAttribute("id");
  console.log(id.substr(0, id.indexOf("_")));
  let table = $("#" + id.substr(0, id.indexOf("_"))).DataTable();
  let data = table.rows().data();
 let text = data.reduce((a, c) => a  + Object.values(c).join(";") + "\n", "");
  let blob = new Blob([text], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" });
  saveAs(blob, "prova.csv");
}
```